# Broken videos posted to LinkedIn via API - video not playing on page, but link works

Tags: linkedin-api

We are now experiencing an error where when we post videos to LinkedIn via the API, the video itself does not play on page - but the link to new tab works. The video has a weird overlay and/or play button where it appears to be clickable, but upon clicking does nothing.

We believe this is a bug. Is LinkedIn going to fix this in the near future? Also, is the potentially related to the whitelist permissions talked about in another thread?

I was directed by LinkedIn Customers Support to post these questions here.

There is no code to show.

Videos posted to LinkedIn via API should play and work properly on page.

Comment: I ran a quick test and I still got the error message saying "does not have permission to create ugc posts" when making the POST request to /ugcPosts. Anything you're doing differently?

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed!

Comment: Do you mind sharing which API endpoint you're using?